# How to remove outer quotes from python list of lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the single quotes(or double quotes if single quote is part of data) from list items and assign to a new list.

I want to transform list0 and assign to list1 such that list1 contains:

```
list1=[AC , AB']
```

I've tried strip and split but it doesn't work when there are single quotes inside double quotes as data.

```
list0=['AC ', " AB'"]
```

Comment: The quotes are necessary to denote the string.

Comment: your current `list1` is going to throw a syntax error. why do you think what you're trying to do is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve doesn't make any sense. The quotes are necessary to denote that something is a string. In the expected output, you'd have a variable name `AC` and something invalid, being `AC'`.

If what you want is to remove spaces from strings, that would make sense, but it's not what you're asking.

Hope this helps clarify things a little.

Also, for further questions: note that it may help to include why you want to achieve something (here, for example, the question as is makes not much sense, but maybe you're reaching out to a greater goal which does make sense but stays unknown to us) and add all you tried and all you understand, so the answers can be the most specific possible.